# Pandas: Use apply to sum row and column on data frame

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(10), periods=10, freq='D')

columns = ['A','B', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df = df.fillna(0) # with 0s rather than NaNs
data = np.array([np.arange(10)]*3).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
```

Given the **df**, I would like to group by each 'column' and apply a function that calculates the sum of the values for each date divided by the total for that group (A, B, C)?

Example:

```
def total_calc(grp):
    sum_of_group = np.sum(group)
    return sum_of_group
```

I am trying to use the 'apply' function on my data frame in this fashion but the **axis=1** only works on rows and **axis=0** works on columns and I want to get both data points for each group?

```
df.groupby(["A"]).apply(total_calc)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am really confuse, what do you mean Given the df, I would like to group by each 'column' and apply a function that calculates the sum of the values for each date divided by the total for that group (A, B, C)? you want to sum(columns) and divide each values by that sum? can you give us a 1 row example? as an example sum of row 2 is 3, what do you want to do with that? you juste want to divide all column by 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure of your question so I'll guess it. First off I don't like to use integer value so let's transform your df to float

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

if you want to divide each element of column A by the sum of column A and vice versa you could do this :

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=0), axis=1)
Out[24]: 
                   A         B         C
2016-09-24  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2016-09-25  0.022222  0.022222  0.022222
2016-09-26  0.044444  0.044444  0.044444
2016-09-27  0.066667  0.066667  0.066667
2016-09-28  0.088889  0.088889  0.088889
2016-09-29  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111
2016-09-30  0.133333  0.133333  0.133333
2016-10-01  0.155556  0.155556  0.155556
2016-10-02  0.177778  0.177778  0.177778
2016-10-03  0.200000  0.200000  0.200000
```

Comment: "to divide each element of column A by the sum of column A and vice versa" --- this is  exactly what i was  trying to do. What about divide by zero error here though?

Comment: the NaN is because the sum of row 1 is 0, so divide by 0 = NaN,  what you are looking for is the second example

Comment: I am looking to get the sum of row 1 which is 0 divide by the sum of column 'A'? I thought that was the second example?

Comment: @Warz, I edited the answer to isolate the "to divide each element of column A by the sum of column A and vice versa" answer

Comment: sorry to come back to this.. is there a way to do this instead of by the 'axis' , choosing the column to apply the division on. I have data in the same frame that is non-numeric

Comment: @Warz you can select your column first `df['list_of_col'] = df['list_of_col'] .div(df['list_of_col'] .sum(axis=0), axis=1)`